# How can we get more than two users from the database randomly in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Well I am creating profile of every new user with signals and I am trying to add some default followers in the new user profile. I am trying with the following code and that is actually doing quite fine but not exactly that thing which i am wishing to do. Well with the following code. first 2 users with pk=1,pk=2 are becoming default followers of every new profile. I wish i could give some random users as a followers to every new user.

For example: first user created new account and get two users following by default with pk=1 ,pk=2 than second user created new account and get two users following by default with different primary key such as pk=2 , pk = 4.

Code: With the following code every new user is getting the same two 2 users with pk=1,pk=2, I dont want that. How can do that things which i have explained with example. Please help cause i need in this case. I shall be very thankful to you. if more detail or code is needed than tell me. I will share that with you.

```
def create_profile(sender, created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        default_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user__pk=1)[0]
        default_user_profile.follower.add(instance)
        userprofile.follower.add(default_user_profile.user)
        userprofile.follower.add(2)
```

Other error.

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/add/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 99, in add_view
    return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 126, in _add_view
    return super().add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1638, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1565, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1081, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 793, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\models.py", line 48, in create_profile
    userprofile.follower.add(f1, f2)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 944, in add
    self._add_items(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1119, in _add_items
    target_ids = self._get_target_ids(target_field_name, objs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1061, in _get_target_ids
    raise TypeError(

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/auth/user/add/
Exception Value: 'User' instance expected, got <UserProfile: onwer UserProfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import random

users_scope = User.objects.all().exclude(pk=my_user_pk)

user_count = users_scope.count()
user_index_1, user_index_2 = random.sample(range(user_count - 1), 2)

follower1 = users_scope[user_index_1]
follower2 = users_scope[user_index_2]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can obtain two random `UserProfile` objects with:

```
UserProfile.objects.order_by('?')[:2]
```

so we can add these with

```
def create_profile(sender, created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        following = list(UserProfile.objects.order_by('?')[:2])
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        userprofile.follower.add(*following)
```

but if the number of `UserProfile`s get larger, this will take considerable time. It will generate a random number for each `UserProfile` and then retrieve the two with the highest number, which might not be ideal.

We can make use of a more *pseudo-random* approach that is less random, but more efficient:

```
from random import sample

def create_profile(sender, created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        pk_range = UserProfile.objects.count()
        k1, k2 = sample(range(pk_range), 2)
        f1 = UserProfile.objects.all()[k1]
        f2 = UserProfile.objects.all()[k2]
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        userprofile.follower.add(f1.user_id, f2.user_id)
```

This will work, given there are of course at least *already* two `UserProfile`s. So we can guard against the condition where there are not yet two `UserProfile`s with:

```
from random import sample

def create_profile(sender, created,instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        pk_range = UserProfile.objects.count()
        if pk_range > 1:
            k1, k2 = sample(range(pk_range), 2)
            f1 = UserProfile.objects.all()[k1]
            f2 = UserProfile.objects.all()[k2]
            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
            userprofile.follower.add(f1.user_id, f2.user_id)
```

Comment: Umm! i paste this code and 'default_user_profile' is undefined and also in (pk__gte=k) ,k is also undefined.

Comment: @FlashMaddy: shouldn't you add it to the `userprofile`? In your code it looks like you add the created `UserProfile` to the followers of the `default_user_profile`, and `2` as well. So the last line in your signal adds the first follower to the second. Anyway, updated.

Comment: Well now when i try to register a new user it shows me this error : TypeError at /admin/auth/user/add/

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'UserProfile' and 'int'

Comment: @FlashMaddy: did you use an asterisk in `.add(*following)`? Exactly *what* is the traceback?

Comment: Yes I have used asterisk and I have added screenshot of traceback in my question. you can see that.

Comment: @FlashMaddy: well the sad part is that relevant info is just at the bottom :). Can't you copy the *text*?

Comment: Yes I have pasted the traceback in question. and remove the screenshot

Comment: Now it is showing me some database error I have added traceback of that error and remove the old one from question can see that. the error shows that:DatabaseError at /admin/auth/user/add/

ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.

Comment: @FlashMaddy: on what database do you work, on a MySQL database this works fine...

Comment: Mysql lite ,Which django provides

Comment: Umm is it resolvable ?

Comment: @FlashMaddy: well in an ideal world the ORM can indeed take care of it. But MySQLite it, as the name says a bit a "light" version. Anyway, edited to simpler (but more expensive) querying.

Comment: Umm sorry my apologizes. I was using signals in a wrong way I fixed that and now it showing me this error: DatabaseError at /admin/auth/user/add/

ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.

Comment: @FlashMaddy: yes, and this is because MySQLite has a limited syntax. So I edited the answer to more simpler querying (which will however result in more queries).

Comment: That is sample because that is sample not defined ?

Comment: @FlashMaddy: you need to import it `from random import sample`.,

Comment: Well to be very honestly is it that much hard ? cause I imported sample than run the server and when I add new user I show me an other error which is :TypeError at /admin/auth/user/add/

'User' instance expected, got <UserProfile: onwer UserProfile>

Comment: @FlashMaddy: so the `follower` is a `ManyToManyField` to `User`, not `UserProfile`? Then it is `.add(f1.user_id, f2.user_id)`